# How to convert x and y coordinates into a heat map in excel?

Tags: excel, heatmap, scatter-plot

I currently have a data set of x and y coordinates (position of an animal in an arena) over a period of time. I just used the coordinates to plot a scatter plot of what that looks like. However, instead of having every single coordinate as a separate point, i was wondering if there was a way to create a heat map of the points? So, the higher the likelihood of the animal in a specific area/ similar coordinates, the warmer the color? Hoping for the final product to be a depiction of the arena with a gradient of colors based on the likelihood the animal explores those regions?

Comment: Would a bubble chart work for you? Size of bubble would be count of x,y coordinates.

Comment: Apparently the bubble scatter plot only takes 255 entries and mine is thousands, so I guess not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with that many points, I don't know if Excel is the right choice if wanting to color-coordinate. The site https://app.rawgraphs.io/ has some really cool graphing capabilities. I use this when needing sankey's or something unusual that Excel cannot easily handle.

Here I used 1500 x/y points between 0 and 20. Then I selected the graph type called "Contour Plot".

Would this work?

[image]

Or here's a Hexagonal Binning chart of the same data...

[image]